# kivy buildozer Compile Error pythonforandroid.toolchain

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

```
 Compile platform
 Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m 
pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=main -- 
bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=kivy,python3 --arch armeabi- 
v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage- 
dir=/home/sysop/kivy3/Build/.buildozer/android/platform/build
```

I have tried download android-for-python , and specify in buildozer.spec file p4a items also compile failed

```
p4a.source_dir = /home/sysop/kivy3/python-for-android
Install platform
Command failed: pip install -q --user

Buildozer failed to execute the last command
```

my vm os : Linux Mint 19.2 Tina \n \l
Linux VmBox 4.15.0-54-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 10:55:24 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

Ohh yeh I solved the issue , after get fresh buildozer installed from the github
also solved some cache/pip directory ownership permission problem

Answer (score 0):

when I mainly use this key value , I can build almost each api level

## (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.

android.api = 27

while I use this key , only 21 or 22 can be built
falied compilation most time

## (int) Minimum API your APK will support.

## android.minapi = 22