# Erros ao compilar apk-kivy usando Buildozer.ova and Crystax

Tags: python-3.x, linux, kivy, buildozer

I installed Virtualbox and [KivyBuildozer.ova](https://kivy.braintrainerplus.com/latest.ova), Xubunto, Crystax, on my Windows 8.1 Pro PC. I did all the procedures, and that was my only obstacle..

```
Media/PasteWithCode/ buildozer init

Media/PasteWithCode/ build android debug
```

But just after long minutes of compilation, with everything appearing to be working, it returns this error in the terminal:

```
Warning: File /home/kivy/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. 
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.                      
# Command failed: /media/sf_Compartilhada/crystax-ndk- 
10.3.2/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools

# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

The code in the .py file I want to compile is very simple, just a button on the screen.

Comment: You copied/pasted many lines of "error text" ... but I don't see anything about what *CAUSED* "pythonforandroid.toolchain" to fail.  Q: Is there any chance the actual error was written to "stderr" ... but you only copied "stdout"?  Q: Or perhaps the actual error is in some other log file?  All the text you gave us says is that "something failed".  It doesn't give any clues as to *WHY* it failed :(

Comment: Of course, but that's what the terminal returned ... I'll edit and add something else

Comment: See if you have any logs in your `.kivy` folder.  Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331728/) and [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/727)

Comment: If you are referring to the files created, yes, they are; a ".buildozer" folder; a "bin" folder and a "buildozer.spec" file. The "bin" folder is the only empty one.

Comment: Logs.  We were looking for log files.   We needed a meaningful error message; logs were a good place to look.  FORTUNATELY ... you checked "stderr" ... and FINALLY game up with something useful :)  Thank you for updating your post :)

Comment: Sooooo:  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61111245/ or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807851/.  Specifically: consider updating or reinstalling Cython

Comment: I tried using Crystax, but it returns this error above ...